# How to use SQLite database created with custom collation, in an environment where this collation is unavailable?

Tags: sqlite

Suppose I register a custom collation `my_collation` which, for example, orders digit strings as integers. Then I create and populate a table `foo` with a primary key on the column `bar` using this collation:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
    bar TEXT PRIMARY KEY COLLATE my_collation,
    quux INT
);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('1000', 1000), ('1', 1), ('123', 123), ('12', 12);
```

When I subsequently open this database in an environment that does not have this custom collation registered (e.g. `sqlite3` CLI shell) I'm unable to query this table:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM foo;
Parse error: no query solution
```

Obviously I don't expect to be able to `INSERT`/`DELETE`, `UPDATE` the `bar` column or even to `SELECT` with constraints on `bar`, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM foo
WHERE bar = '12';
```

since all these require comparing `bar` values via the unavailable collation. But I don't understand why I can't just `SELECT` the entire table.

Why can't I, and how do I get the data out?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47095400/exporting-a-sqlite3-table-from-a-db-with-error-no-such-collation-sequence-iun

Comment: If you registered the custom collation with a loadable extension, simply load the extension in the CLI shell.